# Array to a hash, ruby code reduction

Tags: ruby

I have an array of `thing` objects, each of which has an array of categories. I'd like to build a category hash with a category ID for a key and an array of things for a value.

```
category_hash = Hash.new

things.each { |thing|
  thing.categories.each { |category|
    category_hash[category] = Array.new unless category_hash[category]
    category_hash[category] << thing
  }
}
```

Purely for education, how can this be shortened?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways of making this more idiomatic:

- A trivial note, but don't use `Array.new`.

  Use `[]`, it's shorter, clearer, and [more idiomatic](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#user-content-collections)
- Don't use `category_hash[category] = [] unless category_hash[category]`

  Instead, use `category_hash[category] ||= []`. In general you can use `a ||= b` instead of `a = b unless a`. In the case of hashes, you can skip this completely and just give the hash an appropriate default value:

  ```
  category_hash = Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = [] }
  ```
- Don't initialize a collection to an empty state, and then iterate over another collection, appending to the new collection. Use `map`/`each_with_object`/`inject`/etc. to turn one collection *into* another collection

A more idiomatic solution might look like this:

```
category_hash = things.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |thing,hash|
  thing.categories.each { |cat| hash[cat] << thing }
end
```

A completely different approach would be to map each `thing`'s categories into a new hash, and then merge the resulting hashes. The problem is that you need a "deep" merge, like [the one that comes with ActiveSupport](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge):

```
categories_hash = things.map do |thing|
  Hash[thing.categories.map { |cat| [cat,thing] }]
end.reduce(&:deep_merge)
```